# Xquery - Declare a function to get the MAX value of the input sequence

Tags: xml, xquery

I need to find the MAX value of the input sequence. Hence I have a function below but I think it's too complicated. May you please suggest if there is a easier way to do so?

declare function local:max(
$seq as xs:anyAtomicType*
) as xs:anyAtomicType{

let $head:= head($seq)

let $tail:= tail($seq)

return

if(empty($seq)) then

0.0000001

else

let $temp := local:max($tail)

return if ( $head > $temp)

then $head

else $temp

};

local:max(
(
1,5,2,19
)
)

Return value is 19

Comment: Why can't you use the `max` function provided by XPath? https://maxtoroq.github.io/xpath-ref/fn/max.html

Answer (score 2):

The recursive structure of your function is exactly the one encoded by the higher-order XQuery function [`fn:fold-right($seq, $start, $func)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-fold-right). So by providing the comparison and initial value, you can get the same functionality much more concisely:

```
declare function local:max($seq as xs:anyAtomicType*) as xs:anyAtomicType? {
  fn:fold-right($seq, 0.0000001, function($next, $max) {
    if($max >= $next) then $max else $next
  })
};
```

Since it does not matter in this case if you process the items from left to right or from right to left, it can be advantageous to use `fn:fold-left(...)` instead, which can potentially take advantage of streaming evaluation of the input sequence. It is also more typical in XQuery to return the empty sequence `()` if the input is empty (this is also what `fn:max(...)` does). Making these two changes results in:

```
declare function local:max2($seq as xs:anyAtomicType*) as xs:anyAtomicType? {
  fold-left($seq, (), function($max, $next) {
    if($max >= $next) then $max else $next
  })
};
```